# Is it possible to find the custom scrollbar css property of a dom node in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

If I have an element styled with scrollbar pseudoclasses (eg in chrome), is it possible to find a css property of that pseudoclass? An example:

```
<body><div #a></div></body>
<style>
  #a::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px
  }
</style>
```

I've tried using `getComputedStyle(domNode,'::-webkit-scrollbar').width`, but its not returning the correct value.

Comment: Have a look at http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ and the `.is()`, because JQuery's `.is()` method can check for css selctors.

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the element's offset by its client size which will give the scroll bar size.

```
var myDiv = document.getElement...

var verticalScrollBarWidth = myDiv.offsetWidth - myDiv.clientWidth;

var horizontalScrollBarHeight = myDiv.offsetHeight - myDiv.clientHeight;
```

Here are two properties:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement, "verticalScrollBarWidth", {
    get: function() {
        var tmpWidth = HTMLElement.offsetWidth - HTMLElement.clientWidth;

        if (tmpWidth > 0)
            return tmpWidth;

       return -1;
    },
    set: undefined
});

Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement, "horizontalScrollBarHeight", {
    get: function() {
        var tmpHeight = HTMLElement.offsetHeight - HTMLElement.clientHeight;

        if (tmpHeight > 0)
            return tmpHeight;

       return -1;
    },
    set: undefined
});
```

Usage:

```
var myDiv = document.getElement...

var vScrollBarWidth = myDiv.verticalScrollBarWidth;
var hScrollBarWidth = myDiv.horizontalScrollBarHeight;
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll do this since I am in fact just trying to get the scrollbar width. However, this doesn't answer the question as it is. Also see my comment to Tobiq, getComputedStyle *is* in fact supposed to be able to access css pseudoclass styles.

Comment: Yeah. I can't help you with getting the css, sorry about that.